What are the most basic rules of Gwent?
Anyone who has played the training mode in Gwent will notice that it is completely flooded by day one absolute beginners who are tossed into online mode without a clue even about the most basic things, since there isn't much in the way of a tutorial available.
What are the core fundamental game mechanics you need to know before playing a game against other players?
Not talking about the meaning of various cards but just the most bare bones game mechanics. How many cards are there, who wins, what are points for etc.

A game of Gwent is played as best of 3 rounds.
Whoever has the highest score when both players have passed wins the round. Score has no other meaning - you don't carry points over to the next round and the summary of the total score has no bearing over who wins the game. Only round wins matter.
This means that if you are either in the lead and the opponent has passed, or you are hopelessly behind and the opponent has passed, you should stop playing. There is no point to keep playing when you have already secured the round win and there's a big disadvantage to keep playing if you can't beat a passed opponent's score within the next turn.
Cards are resources. You get 10 cards at the beginning of the game, then draw 3 cards at the beginning of each round. You can never have more than 10 cards on your hand - if you draw cards when you have 10 already, you have to swap a card in your hand with the card drawn. Cards not played in the current round will get kept to the next.
If you have fewer cards than your opponent you are at severe disadvantage. If you won the first round but have 1 card less than your opponent, then a sensible standard tactic in round 2 is to pass without playing a card. This means that you'll enter the final round with as many cards as your opponent. You will still be at an advantage since you get to play the final card.
The aim of each round is:

Round 1. Try to win by having equal amount of cards as your opponent, or just one card less than them. A common tactic is to not burn too many of your strongest gold cards early on.
Round 2. A player with an advantage from round 1 can make a play for the win. Otherwise, it is common that the one who won round 1 with one card less passes.
Round 3. The finale. Whoever starts the round is at disadvantage.

And that's about it. The rest of the answer is about more advanced concerns.

Based on the above mechanics, we can draw the following conclusions about fundamental tactics:

Passing early when you have 7 cards or more in round 1 is dangerous. Because then the opponent will not only win round 1, they can also play for the win in round 2, since they will draw a full hand.
Whenever you pass and lose with an equal amount of cards as your opponent in round 1 (because you started the round), the opponent can also play for the win in round 2 as you have equal amounts of cards. Some decks are stronger than others with few cards.
Alternatively, if both players have the same amount of cards in round 2 and it is less than 7 cards, the winner of round 1 can pass without playing a card and thereby enter the last round with one card more as well as the final turn, which is a massive advantage. Whoever won round 1 can always freely play cards in round 2 until they have 7 remaining and then pass without risking ending up with less cards in round 3.
Whoever won round 1 can of course always play for the win in round 2 even if they have one card less, but that's a risky gamble which might cost you the game. Trying for the win with one less card could mean that you lose and have to play the final round with one card less.
In round 1 or 2, if you didn't start the round but have higher score than your opponent when it is your turn, and your opponent have 4 or less cards, it is wise to pass. This will either force them to pass with one card less and lose the round or make a play to win the round, but then with 2 cards less. Either way you end up with more cards than your opponent and this is very often a game-winning move.
For this reason, if you started round 1 and is about to play with 4 cards or less remaining and the card played will not place you in the lead, you risk ending up with less cards. Passing is a sensible damage control tactic at that point.
The number of 4 cards or less is significant, because if someone wins round 1 with 4 cards or more remaining, they can always draw 3 cards in round 2, pass, then draw 3 more in the final round, getting 10 even if their opponent had more cards than them after round 1.

Also, using up all of your leader's ability in the first rounds is often a bit of a disadvantage because it is roughly equal to some 2-3 cards and the normal tactic is to save it for round 3.
